# How did you handle with the Eliminate render-blocking resources and Limit unused CSS in Magento 2

Tags: css, pagespeed, google, render-blocking, pagespeed-insights

How did you handle with the **Eliminate render-blocking resources** in Magento 2 and **Limit unused CSS** it is about real treatments.

I have enabled Varnish, Minify CSS, JS, WebP, Image attributes added.

Answer (score 0):

Following should be done :

1. For server end: -- Varnish -- make sure most of the pages are delivered from varnish Cache.
   For Front end: 2. CDN: for JS, CSS, and Media use of CDN will reduce hop time which in turn means faster pages.
2. Critical CSS
3. Remove unwanted JS using requierJS and Require config JS.
4. Differ JS or Async objective load it as late as possible.
5. Advance Bundle JS
6. WebP and responsive images to reduce image payload.
   Check google PSI tool apply FCP and LCP filters and check.

Also go through this link :

[Guide to Magento optimization](https://www.oscprofessionals.com/blog/speedup-magento-2-the-ultimate-guide/)